# Gutenberg block - remove setting for core/file

Tags: block-editor

I want to remove this setting from the core block "file":

[image]

I've tried to do this in theme.json

```
{
"version": 2,
"settings": {
    "blocks": {
        "core/file": {
            "showDownloadButton": false
        }
    }
}
```

}

But it doesn't work. Anybody know how to accomplish this? I feel like the documentation for all things Gutenberg is a bit lackluster? Or maybe I'm just bad at finding what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you were able to get this working, but i did this using the
`register_block_type_args` filter in our `functions.php`

```
 function show_download_button( $settings, $blockname ) {
    
        // Check for block type.
        if ( $blockname !== 'core/file' ) {
    
            return $settings;
        }
    
        $downloadbutton = [
            'type'    => 'boolean',
            'default' => false,
        ];
    
        $settings['attributes']['showDownloadButton'] = $downloadbutton;
    
        return $settings;
    }
    
    
    add_filter( 'register_block_type_args', 'show_download_button', 10, 2 );
```